# Words with doubled letters. Perl

Tags: regex, perl

How can i find words with doubled letters(**e.g. progress, tool and so on**) in text using regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "katttaarww";
my @arr = $str =~ /(.)\1+/g;
print join "~", @arr;
```

output

```
t~a~w
```

Comment: Isn't `\g1` more preferrable?

Comment: @mpapec `\g1` instead of `\1` to refer to a previous group

Comment: @mpapec : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences

Comment: @Zaid can't tell about that, since I'm rarely using first one, and never second one. :)

Comment: I seemed to remember [this warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241), which is for the RHS is `s///` (nothing mentioned about LHS)

Comment: Please comment on down votes.

Comment: looks fine to me (so got an upvote). Is there any problem with it?

Comment: `\g1` is fine, but not available in older versions of perl

Comment: it finds outputs letters, how could i get whole word with double letters?

Comment: @sliddy check https://eval.in/165586

Answer (score 0):

use a backreference to a single wildcard capture group, see below:

```
a = "hello"
a =~ /(.)\1/
```